# Python can't find the module I created

Tags: python, module

My project directory has this structure:

```
src
 |__model
      |___models.py
      |___ prepare_data.py
 |_utils.py
```

`models.py` imports a function from  `prepare_data.py`, which imports a function from `utils.py`.

When I run the script from bash, if I'm in the `model` folder the command is:
`python models.py` and I get the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

If instead I run the command from the src folder with `python model/models.py` the error I get is
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prepare_data'`

I know that moving `utils.py` in the `model` directory would fix the problem but I don't want to do that. I tried using the `-m` argument with dotted notation. So the second command becomes:
`python -m model.models`, but I still get the same error. What can I do to fix it?

EDIT: I also tried putting an empty `__init__.py` file in the root directory but it didn't fix the problem

EDIT 2: I solved the problem by typing this at the beginning of the
`model.py` module, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612922/14779080):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty `__init__.py` file in the root of your directory https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

That lets python know it should treat the contents as a package.

Comment: In Python 3 directories are more-or-less automatically treated as packages.  The problem is if you run a module in a package directly it won't be able to resolve the package structure properly.  If you want to make a file in your package executable there needs to be a `__main__.py` module somewhere.

Comment: I created the file, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

From source folder run the command and the error you are saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prepare_data'`
You are using it like this:

```
import prepare_data
```

But now use:

```
import model.prepare_data
```

Comment: I just found an alternative solution to my problem, but also your solution would have worked. I don't know why I didn't think about that since I had already done that in the past